# Swift - create a back button without navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have an app that has a toolbar, but I don't want the bar at the top, in order to free more viewing space. Therefore I have decided not to use a navigation controller. I'd like to add a back button to the toolbar. How would I go about this?

Adding the button is easy enough, and setting the action to performSegueWithIdentifier is all fine, but what happens is that the previous view just gets loaded again, rather than show it as it was, like a true back button. So if I tap on the 10th row on a tableView and go to a new page, when I press the back button it loads the view from the top again, instead of showing it as where I scrolled down to last.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Even though you don't want a `UINavigationBar`, you **do** want a `UINavigationController` in this case, because it manages the 'back stack' exactly the way you want it. Just hide its navigation bar by setting its [`navigationBarHidden`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/navigationBarHidden) property to `true` (in the Storyboard or in the `viewDidLoad` function of the root view controller).

You can then use `navigationController.popViewController(true)` as normal, in response to the user clicking your custom back button.

Comment: if you use navigationBarHidden, the content of the controller is still shifted down just the navigation bar is hidden.

Comment: @SpyZip, what is the solution to this shift, if any?